# Algorithm of automatic ee.Image visualization used by Map.addLayer

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, visualisation

The following code:

```
var image = ee.Image("MODIS/051/MCD12Q1/2001_01_01").select(["Land_Cover_Type_1"])
Map.addLayer(image, {}, '2');
```

gives an RGB visualization displayed on the map, but `Export.image.toCloudStorage` is exporting image as-is (without any conversion), so the result differs.

**Question:**
In which rules does `Map.addLayer` performs this conversion? Which methods can be used to reproduce it when exporting (`Export.image.toCloudStorage`)?

Adding `.visualise(<noArgs>)` before exporting may give different results than `Map.addLayer`

[image: Export.image.toCloudStorage][image: Map.addLayer]

`Export.image.toCloudStorage` **(left)** VS `Map.addLayer` **(right)** [path: /8/152/89]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an image (or collection, if its in one) has pre-defined metadata properties of the form "_class_palette" and
_class_values", and the user has provided no visualization options, then Map.addLayer applies them as follows:

```
var palette = image.get("landcover_class_palette")
var values = image.get("landcover_class_values")
var max = values.size().subtract(1)
var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, max)
image.remap(values, sequence).visualize({min:0, max:max, palette: palette})
```

Comment: What if more bands are in the source ee.Image? I suspect map.AddLayer only performs this action when there is one band. When I added more bands, the result was not styled, am I right?

Comment: Correct.  Only if there's a single band.

Answer (score 4):

If you print the image to the console, you will see that one of the properties is called `Land_Cover_Type_1_class_palette`, and another called `Land_Cover_Type_1_class_values`. The symbology is taken directly from the palette property for the corresponding pixel values in the class values property.

[image]