# Difference in implementation of ee.Image.getMapId and Export.map.toCloudStorage for float casting

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

**Background**

The following code:

```
image_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
filtered_collection = image_collection.filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-02-01').filterBounds(region)


def map_clouds(img):
    scl = img.select("SCL").rename("CLOUDS")
    mask = scl.eq(7).Or(scl.eq(8)).Or(scl.eq(9))
    return mask


mapped_collection = filtered_collection.map(map_clouds)
measurements_count_per_pixel = filtered_collection.count().select("SCL").rename("CLOUDS")
aggregated_image = mapped_collection.sum()
normalized_image = aggregated_image.divide(measurements_count_per_pixel)
result_image = normalized_image.clip(region)
```

produces `ee.Image` (`result_image`) which results can be displayed two ways:

- by `ee.Image.getMapId()`
- by `Export.map.toCloudStorage()`

Both of these methods generate maptiles, so the results should be similar (especially after [visualisation adjustment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426633/algorithm-of-automatic-ee-image-visualization-used-by-map-addlayer)). The problem occurs when the `ee.Image` is in float data type.

For `ee.Image.getMapId()` the result is as expected, but `Export.map.toCloudStorage()` raise en exception:

> Image to render must have integer-valued bands, but band "CLOUDS" is
> floating-point.

One of the solutions is to cast `ee.Image` to int type (`ee.Image.toInt()`) before exporting but the effect is different than in usage of `ee.Image.getMapId`

**Question:**
`ee.Image.getMapId` has to deal with float types somehow, what algorithm should be implemented before exporting (`Export.map.toCloudStorage()`) to get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getMapId`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-getmapid), like `Map.addLayer` in the Code Editor, includes a *visualization* step — implicitly calling [`ee.Image.visualize()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-visualize). This algorithm converts an image of an arbitrary type and bands into an image with RGB bands whose values are rescaled and clipped to be in the integer range 0-255.

It seems that [`Export.map.toCloudStorage()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-map-tocloudstorage) doesn't provide that automatically, but you can just apply `.visualize()` to the image before the export step to get the same results.

Comment: what if someone has already .visualize() in code with parameters? Won't calling visualize again break it?

Comment: @Yas I'm not sure exactly what scenario you're imagining, but `.visualize()` will generally leave an already visualized image unchanged (unless explicitly given parameters that change the band selection or scaling).